# how to show data from mysql in php where a trash != 1 (column value)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show only that rows where **Trash** != 1 from php mysql in php. **Trash** variable is column field of php mysql where i stored a value of 1. so that I retrieve only rows where **Trash** = null

```
//Below mentioned code for check order status
$o_status = @$_GET['o_status'];
if(isset($o_status) and !empty($o_status)){
$o_where = array('order_s'=>$o_status);
}else if(isset($type) and !empty($type)){
  //$o_where = array('status'=>1,'order_show_off'=>"No",'status'=>1);
}else{
  //$o_where = array('status'=>1, 'status'=>1);
}

//And in last line of code for searching for all data
$cou_list = $con->all_fetch("orders",$o_where," group by order_id, vendor_id order by id desc");
```

Thank you in advance

I am expecting a solution for my problem in code terminology or maybe some guidance

Answer (score 0):

you should make a query with the where clause for example

```
Select * From tables Where (Trash = Null)
```

Comment: It'd need to be `IS NULL` to test for null in sql. `=` does not work for that

Comment: yes or you can use `Where Trash != 1`

Comment: You should [edit] your answer